# iis7 ftp user isolation to have 2 users with same home directory

Tags: iis, iis-7, ftp, windows-server-2008

I have successfully set-up IIS7 ftp user isolation but I was questioned about how to set up 2 different users to have same "Home Folder"?

As long as we need to set up each folder with the exactly username inside of a LocalUser folder, I am not sure how to proceed.

From the 5 types we have I am using 'user name directory option'.

Is it possible to set-up such a configuration?

Thanks